# Which letter represents the angle?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I choose S and R but both are wrong, does anyone know the right angle?
[image: Choose the right letter]

Comment: Position of $-4,13 \pi/4$ occupies same position as $-4,5 \pi/4.$ It  comes to position $R$ with $+4$ and finally to position $P$ in first quadrant with $-4$ sign of amplitude.

Answer (score 2):

The angle $\frac{13\pi}{4}=3\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}$ corresponds to R, since angles are measured counterclockwise around the circle. Then, since the radius in negative, you reflect through the origin. So, the answer is P.